# How is this spam?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage, spam

I was in the Triage queue and [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/31514427) popped up.

> Any single place / tool / site to list all AWS regions an AWS service is available in?

I went into the flag menu and then decided otherwise from flagging (as this question did make some sense) and apparently it's deleted for "spam or nonsense?" How is this spam?

Comment: There's a deleted answer by the user on the question which is spam, making the question likely spam seed, and presumably why the question was deleted as spam.

Comment: @cigien So in reviews we are expected to go through both the answer *and* the question and not rely on what is already displayed?

Comment: It's a bad (spam audit) indeed, but you shouldn't have picked "Looks OK" anyway. It's asking for off-topic resources, which is flag worthy.

Comment: No, reviews should be reviewable in isolation, in principle. In this case, I'm not sure "Looks OK" is the right triage review for a recommendation question though.

Comment: It's definitely not; the correct review is "unsalveagable", specifically flagging the question for closure ("Needs improvement" -> "A community-specific reason" -> "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more")

Comment: @cigien is correct there are 4 identical answers all containing the exact same link:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71522469/15497888), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71522441/15497888), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71522213/15497888) and the answer on this question makes [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71522150/15497888). This question was likely cleaned up as part of that effort.

Comment: It's arguable that this **might** be a fine question on its own, perhaps with some edits (official-resource requests are generally on-topic, although this one may be off-topic as relating to server administration).  It was deleted for being a spam seed.  But yes, it's a terrible audit.  It's been redeleted with a Rude flag so that it won't show up for anyone else.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @RyanM So, you re-re-deleted with an R/A flag, given that it was already deleted with an R/A flag? :)

Comment: @Makyen a fact that I noticed about a minute after doing so and posting that comment.  Whoops.  Bit too slow :-)

Comment: @RyanM Thank you, but won't this count to my failed audits? I have been banned a couple times but I usually submit helpful (i think) reviews now and don't want a longer ban.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.  There's not much we can do about that right now (we can't "forgive" audit failures), but if you do get a review suspension that includes that post as one of the failed audits, shoot us a flag including a link to this post (just flag any of your own posts as "in need of moderator intervention") and we'll look into fixing that for you.

Comment: @0xLogN IMO, "Looks OK" is not an appropriate response for that question. It's a resource request, which is an explicit off-topic reason, which makes "Looks OK" wrong.

Comment: Yet another audit that did a good job showing that "looks ok" is not the correct option here and yet it got removed from the audit pool. What's the point in having audits anyway when they only teach: go complain on meta and some mod will fix it for you?

Comment: @Tom Ideally, a failed audit provides enough information such that the reviewer can figure out what they did wrong and learn from the experience. In this case, the fact that the question is indicated by the system as spam makes the result of the audit a bit confusing as to *why* "Looks OK" is wrong, as demonstrated by this question. While the question could be a reasonable audit if it wasn't indicated as spam, removing it from the audit pool avoids additional users being confused by the fact that it was treated as spam, as why it was treated as spam isn't obvious without a wider context.

Comment: @Makyen The triage review doesn't switch from "normal triage" to "spam or ok" just because the system notifies the user that the post was marked as spam. It tells the user to looks closely if there is a problem with the post and even if the reviewer doesn't see why the question was marked as spam, it doesn't release them from the obligation to check for other issues as well. That a reviewer might not understand why the system said that post was spam is ok, I can accept that, but I can't accept that they still chose "looks ok" and use "it's not spam" as a reason to select that option.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

##### The question was treated as a spam seed.

In about an hour, the user who authored the question posted 4 spam-like answers, 3 of them near-duplicates, none of them more than link-only, all linking to the same site, which is not an official AWS source (i.e. the domain was registered on 2021-09-26, isn't registered to Amazon, and is using privacy to not disclose the owner(s)). One of those answers was on the off-topic, resource-request question which your review task was about. I treated the question as a [spam seed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256709/what-is-a-spam-seed), as the user rapidly posting 4 very similar answers on only marginally related questions indicates that their intent was to spam the information about that site, which makes their question look a lot like a spam seed.

While the question is a reasonable audit, it's not a reasonable audit as *spam*. In order to remove the question from the audit pool, it was undeleted and re-deleted as rude/abusive, which prevents it from being used as an audit.

##### Ignoring the spam aspects, "Looks OK" wasn't correct.

You responded to that audit with "Looks OK". That's not a correct response for that question (ignoring the spam seed issue). The question is clearly and explicitly asking for an off-site resource. Such questions are off-topic and should be closed. There's an exception to that, in that questions asking for an *official* source for a *programming related* resource are permitted. That question was definitely not asking for an official source. While it might have been edited to be asking for an official source, or even better to ask how to use and API to obtain that information, obtaining an official source was definitely not the question author's intent, given that they posted an answer with a non-official source.

[Note: I'm intentionally not saying that the question would be on-topic if it was asking for an official source for the information which it is requesting. IMO, the topicality of a question asking for an official source for that information would be debatable, as the information which the question is asking for really isn't *programming* related, it's entirely about in what geographical/geopolitical regions AWS is offering specific services, which is *deployment*, not really *programming*, IMO.]